# Submit form within Thickbox, then close window

Tags: javascript, php, forms, woocommerce, thickbox

I am using the Woocommerce plugin on my Wordpress site. When you click on a product, it loads a Thickbox iframe window where you input the quantity and add it to the cart. You can view the test site here: `http://75.103.92.37/rent-storage/`

I'd like to have the form submit the data to the shopping cart, then close the window. [This link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/Q_24831988.html) is the closest solution I've found, but works using a "thank you" page which I do not have and would like to avoid using if possible.

This is my form code. I placed an OnSubmit function to close the Thickbox window. It works, but the form does not submit.

```
    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit="javascript:parent.eval('tb_remove()')">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

    <?php
    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() )
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
            'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product )
    ) );
    ?>

    <button type="submit" class="button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

</form>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`tb_remove()` returns `false` so the form would not submit.

You need to add a click handler to "Add to Cart" that runs `tb_remove()` and also returns true.

Since you're submitting the form in an iframe, you need to make sure the "post" fires before removing the iframe from the document.

For usability, it would be nice to also have a message saying your product was added to the cart when the thickbox closes.

Comment: We are working in Woocommerce. Do you know what the click handler would be to trigger the "add to cart" function in Woocommerce?

Comment: @PaulRuocco this is done in javascript and is independent of the PHP framework you're running. The easiest way to do this is to create a javascript function in the parent page like `function closeThickbox() {tb_remove();}`. Then in the iframe add a jquery event like `$("#addtocart").click(function() { parent.closeThickbox(); });`.  Although it looks like you're trying something else now...